# Como podrias calcular la probabilidad de una secuencia infinita de numeros aleatorios del 0 al 9

Tags: matemáticas, matlab

Tengo la siguiente lista:

```
6
4
8
7
6
3
6
4
6
X
```

Se podrían calcular las probabilidades para cada número (0..9) en función a un patrón o promedio de ocurrencias?

Ejemplo:
Nuestro registro dice que después de un 6 viene un 4 ó un 3, y de 9 eventos han ocurrido solo dos veces para el 4 y una vez para el 3, así que, ¿se podría considerar que el 4 tiene la mayor probabilidad de aparecer?

Imagina una lista de 5000 números, ¿se podría comenzar a construir un patrón?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu pregunta va más orientada a la probabilidad y estadistica, en primer punto no es posible generar números aleatorios, solo existen los pseudoaleatorios, tendrias que generar la grafica de tus datos que tienes con una de chi cuadrada por ejemplo, existen muchas más y ya en base a la que encuentres que es el caso, puedes tomarlo y reproducirlo y obtener tu respuesta.

Este enlace te podria ayudar.

https://es.slideshare.net/Crekis3/unidad-iii-generacion-de-numeros-aleatorios-simulacin